# update product quantity on check out page magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to provide functionality to update product quantity on checkout page of magento. so if user want to update the product quantity he can do it on checkout page rather to go back on cart page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by editing item.phtml (template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml) and these lines after line no #47

```
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>   
    <td class="a-center">
        <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" name="update_cart_action" id="cup_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"  class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
    </td>
   <td> <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('shopping-cart-table'); ?>" id="up_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></span></button><td>
```

and put Jquery code at the end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".btn-update").click(function(){


        var id = "#c"+this.id;
        var quan = jQuery(id).val();
        var lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>checkout/cart/updatePosts/",
            data: "cart["+lastChar+"][qty]="+quan,
            async: false,
                success: function(html){

                    location.reload();

                }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

now override cartcontroller.php and place all the functions of the original cartcontroller.php and rename function updatePostAction by function updatePostsAction.
and change the redirect path to $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');

Comment: Its not working. Qty not updated.

Comment: It's Not working

Answer (score 1):

Updating the quantity means that the full quote has to be recalculated invalidating the chosen payment and shipment methods. This will require the user to go back to these steps and choose the new information.

It can probably be done using a custom controller that adds the new quantity then calling that over AJAX for example but after every quantity change you will have to send the user back to the shipment method step or at least prevent him from checking out so he can move back himself. All in all I highly doubt it will be very user friendly.

Comment: yes you are right but can do it by ajax please checkout this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515005/update-product-quantity-on-check-out-page-magento/20537719#20537719

Comment: the above link is not working quantity is not change